# Laravel 5.0 [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

Good afternoon. I have a small problem on my console creating a relationship with two tables in laravel 5.0.

This is my product migration table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 255);
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('extract', 300);
            $table->decimal('price', 8, 2);
            $table->string('quantity', 300);
            $table->string('image', 300);       
            $table->boolean('visible');
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('categories');
            $table->integer('brand_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('brand_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('brands');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('products');
    }

}
```

My product model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug', 'description', 'extract', 'price', 'quantity', 'image', 'visible', 'category_id', 'brand_id'];


    // Relation with Category
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    // Relation with Brand
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand');
    }

    /*public function upload()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Upload');
    }*/

    //Query para buscador
    public function scopeName($query, $name)
    {
        //dd("scope: " . $name);
        $query->where(\DB::raw("CONCAT(name, '', description, '', price, '', quantity)"), "LIKE", "%$name%");
    }
}
```

My category model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    //Query para buscador
    public function scopeName($query, $name)
    {
        //dd("scope: " . $name);
        $query->where(\DB::raw("CONCAT(name)"), "LIKE", "%$name%");
    }
}
```

My brand model:

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Brand extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'brands';

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

    //Query para buscador
    public function scopeName($query, $name)
    {
        //dd("scope: " . $name);
        $query->where(\DB::raw("CONCAT(name)"), "LIKE", "%$name%");
    }
}
```

When I run the migration the following error message is generated:

```
Migration table created successfully.



  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
  : alter table `products` add constraint products_brand_id_foreign foreign k
  ey (`brand_id`) references `brands` (`id`))






  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Someone who can help me?

Comment: Are you sure the catagories and brands tables are being created before the products table when you run migrations?

Comment: Hello aethergy, only the category table was created.

Comment: I mean, in migrations folder, the migrations for catagories and brands should come before products. You can't set a foreign key for a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: When you run artisan migrate it will create tables in the order that the migration files were created. So you need to make sure that the catagories and brands migrations come before the products migration otherwise you will get this error.

Comment: Sometimes, it would also be a good idea to move the foreign key related calls to a third migration file instead of renaming the existing migrations and refreshing your database (especially when working with a team).

Comment: Hey thanks brother, was a matter of logic, it was resolved migrating as last process the Products table, that solved the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for cooperation, solve the problem through responses:

aetherg, Hilmi Erdem KEREN

The problem was the order of the tables to make the migration.